# Necessity of include_directories command in cmake project

Tags: makefile, cmake

I'm following a tutorial on CMake and I have problems understanding the necessity of using the 'include_directories' command at one point.

Let me explain the project first:

In my working directory I have:
- a main.cpp function, a CMakeLists.txt(the main one), a configuration file, a 'MathFunction' directory and a 'build' directory

In the MathFunction directory I have:
- a CMakeLists.txt file that will be invoked by the main one
- A file 'mysqrt.cxx' that contains the implementation of a function which will be used in 'main.cpp' application
- A 'MathFunctions.h' header file that contains the prototype of that function

In the CMakeLists from 'MathFunction' directory I'm creating a library using code from 'mysqrt.cxx' like this:

```
add_library(MathFunctions mysqrt.cxx)
```

This snippet is a part of my main CMake code:

```
# add the MathFunctions library?
#
if (USE_MYMATH)
 include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/MathFunctions") # WHY DO WE NEED THIS
 add_subdirectory (MathFunctions)
 set (EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS} MathFunctions)
endif (USE_MYMATH)

add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)
target_link_libraries (Tutorial MathFunctions)
```

Now I do not understand why I need too add that 'include_directories' command in order to use the library? Shouldn't it be enough that the last command 'target_link_libraries' links the already created executable and libraries togheter so there would be no need to also include_directories?

Thank you for reading and I'm sorry if I have not explained it very well but I hope you will understand what I mean :D

Answer (score 0):

Command `include_directories` sets directories for **header files** (`.h`) to be searched. *Linking* (`target_link_libraries`) with a library basically specifies only a **library file** (`.so`, `.dll` or other type). As you see, these are *different things*.

When linking executable with a library **target**, CMake propagates (more precisely, "consumes") some properties of that library target to the executable. Among these properties there is [INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) property, which adds include directories to the executable.

So, when a library target has *INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES* property correctly being set, you don't need to explicitly specify include directories for executable:

**MathFunctions/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(MathFunctions mysqrt.cxx)
# Among other things, this call sets INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property.
target_include_directories(MathFunctions PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

**CMakeLsits.txt**:

```
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)
# This also propagates include directories from the library to executable
target_link_libraries (Tutorial MathFunctions)
```

Note, that using simple

```
# This *doesn't* set INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property.
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

in `MathFunctions/CMakeLists.txt` doesn't imply propagating include directories to the linked executable.

Comment: Not only are headers and libraries different things, but most relevant to this question they often _live in different directories_.  Header files usually live in some sort of `/path/to/include` directory, while libraries live in some sort of `/path/to/lib` directory.  So, telling cmake where the libraries are isn't enough: you have to also tell it where the headers are.  It can't assume that they're the same.  Also, the order of directories for include can matter so they need to be stated explicitly.

Comment: `Also, the order of directories for include can matter` - It is treated as bad approach to have header files with the same names, So order of include directories is rarely a matter.

Comment: That's true but sometimes, with third party libraries, it's not avoidable.  Also, sometimes you really _want_ it; for example once I created an environment that provided working versions of standard C/C++ header files for systems that had errors in the system-provided ones.  In that environment there were multiple copies of things like `stdio.h` etc. and you needed to choose the correct one.